# Blank Page When Installing Magento Open Source 2.2.2

Tags: php, magento2.2, installation, php-7, zend-framework

I am getting the following error when trying to run the initial php setup script, please advise

```
$ php bin/magento setup:install
Fatal error: Declaration of Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManager::get($name, ?array $options = NULL) must be compatible with Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager::get($name, $options = Array, $usePeeringServiceManagers = true) in /srv/http/magento/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/PluginManager.php on line 211
```

My Setup:

```
$ php -version
  PHP 7.2.0 (cli) (built: Dec  5 2017 18:56:10) ( NTS )
  Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
  Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with the PHP Version and the Zend Framework. You can refer this [link](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mvc/issues/266.)

I think if you downgrade your PHP version there will be no problem in installing.

Comment: Downgraded and everything now works. Even found this handy package for downgrading packages in Arch linux which is normally not very easy https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/downgrade/

Answer (score 0):

i had that with php 7.0.25 and apache 2. after rebooting, setup worked.